# The ConnectionString property has not been initialized for DropDownList

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have the following code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Dynamic Reports</title>
<script language="javascript" src="js/DynamicReports.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body onload="doSelect()">
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDynReports" runat="server" DataSourceID="sdsDynReports" DataTextField="DynReportName" DataValueField="DynReportID">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdsDynReports" runat="server" SelectCommand="select v.object_id as DynReportID, substring(v.name, 11, LEN(v.name)) as DynReportName from sys.views v where v.name like 'DynReport[_]%'">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
</body>
</html>
```

It throws the following error at runtime:

```
The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.
```

My web.config file seems to be okay because I am doing many other sql calls in the .vb code.  This is the first time I am doing sql in .aspx code.

I presume my connection that is available in my .vb code needs to be exposed to the .aspx code.

I am open to a solution that would move the select to the .vb code.

EDIT: I figured out that I should add `ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:constr %>"` to the SqlDataSource element, but the problem is that I do not have connection strings in my web.config file.  My connection strings are in a file called ApplicationConfig.vb.

So, how can I get the connection string out of ApplicationConfig.vb into the .aspx code?

EDIT: I am doing it this way because it is the sample code I found for populating a dropdown from a select statement.  I am a vb.net noob so I am basically surviving by cutting and pasting from the SO.  Suggestions for better ways is cheerfully accepted but I get lost if the example code is not complete.  Example: Some example code I find on SO looks like what I want to do, but it is a series of snip-its and I don't know where to put those snip-its.

EDIT: Add .vb code:

```
Partial Class XXX_CommonPages_DynamicReports
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub dynreport_ServerClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles dynreports_run.ServerClick
    Dim ViewObjectId As String = ddlDynReports.SelectedValue
    Dim DataOut As String = "some,data,out"
    Response.Clear()

    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=DynReport_" + ViewObjectId + ".csv")
    Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"

    Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", DataOut.Length())
    Response.Write(DataOut)
    ' Response.End ' Causes ThreadAbortException.

End Sub

End Class
```

EDIT: Here is the .vb code that contains the connection string:

```
Public Class ApplicationConfig
Public Class AppConfig
    Implements IConfigurationSectionHandler

    Private Const PRODUCTION_DATAACCESS_CONNECTIONSTRING_DEFAULT As String = "serve ..."

    Public Shared ReadOnly Property ConnectionString() As String
        Get
            If fieldConnectionString Is Nothing Then fieldConnectionString = PRODUCTION_DATAACCESS_CONNECTIONSTRING_DEFAULT
            Return fieldConnectionString
        End Get
    End Property

End Class
End Class
```

Comment: Are you missing something in your SqlDataSource markup? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.connectionstring(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Why are you writing code in your aspx page?

Comment: Could you add the code from ApplicationConfig.vb?

Comment: I can't see any particular reason to have the connectionstring hardcoded in this way. The correct place to have a connectionstring is in the web.config file. (And this is the reason we have these shortcuts in the SqlDataSource to reach the connectionstring). You can set the ConnectionString property for the SqlDataSource in the Page_Load event when IsPostBack is false.

Comment: I inherited all this code and am just trying to slog thru it until we can either replace the system or hire a vb guy.  Anyway, I will put the connection string into web.config, and then pull the connection string from web.config for both .aspx code and the ApplicationConfig.vb code.